# Изменить GET-запроса в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно из "cars/?make_id=aston-martin&model_id=vulcan&sorting=popular" превратить в "cars/aston-martin/vulcan?sorting=popular", т.е. изменяться будет только GET make_id и model_id, а остальные GET-запросы без изменений, никак не могу решить данную задачу.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попытки конечно не покажете?

Comment: Пробовал RewriteRule ^make_id(\d+)\/model_id$ cars/?make_id=$1&model_id=$2 [L]

Comment: Примерно понятен масштаб пробела в знаниях, [вот](https://habr.com/ru/post/545150/) на почитать

Comment: Если Вы про то, что буквы нужно в нижний регистр исправить, то это не серьезно, мне главное, чтобы GET запросы make_id и model_id редактировались

Comment: нет, не про это вообще, у вас полностью отсутствует понимание что такое регулярные выражения, вы приводите пример строк и регулярного выражения - совершенно не совместимые между собой, значит пример вы нагуглили в одной из миллиарда статей как сделать чпу и даже не попытались прочесть описание и как именно это работает, а посему для начала - вам стоит ознакомится с базовыми понятиями регулярных выражений чтобы для начала понять что вот это например ```\d+``` - означает "любое число"

Comment: Я брал код с вопросов, которые находятся на этом же сайте, допустим, ошибка была в недопонимании, но сути это не меняет, что мне нужно изменить.
Вам легче станет, если я укажу "RewriteRule ^make_id([a-z]+)\/model_id$ cars/?make_id=$1&model_id=$2 [L]"?

Comment: Мне не тяжело чтоб становилось легче, если вы хотите "готовое решение за минимум усилий" - вы ошиблись сайтом, тут помогают учится а не решают задачки на заказ :) собсно если вдруг у вас появится желание разобраться как сделать самостоятельно - обращайтесь.. а делать за вас работу \ задание совершенно бесплатно - чет лениво :)

Comment: Извиняюсь, но я не вижу здесь никакого обучения, я вижу здесь разные вопросы, на которые люди отвечают, а не обучают. Если Вы обучаете, то и Вам данный сайт не подходит.

Comment: Посмотрите одну из причин "закрытия" вопроса:
**Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.**, ваш вопрос не тянет на проблему специалиста, он слишком тривиален, значит либо это учебное задание, либо вы пытаетесь решать за **ЧУЖОЙ** счет свои проблемы :) ни первое(решение задачек за учеников) ни второе(решение чужой работы) тут не приветствуется :) можете классифицировать свой вопрос в любую сторону, ответ на вопрос от этого не материализуется :)

Comment: з.ы. я просто пытался ввести вас в курс дел на этом сайте :) можете конечно и дальше ждать ответа, но шансов не много с вашим подходом :)

Answer (score 0):

Помогло:

```
RewriteRule ^cars/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ cars/?make_id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cars/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ cars/?make_id=$1&model_id=$2 [NC,L]
```